# Function Split in SQL Server causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to query a comma-separated list of values. But I get an error:

```
SELECT
    nCmpID, cCompanyName  
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM tbl_CompanyMaster  
     WHERE nCmpID IN (SELECT * 
                      FROM dbo.fnsplit((SELECT can_AccessCompanyID 
                                        FROM tbl_UserMenuRelations 
                                        WHERE nUserID = 0 
                                          AND Is_Active = 1 
                                          AND Is_Available = 1), ',') a) 
       AND Is_Active = 1) t
```

My function FNSplit:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
    (@sInputList VARCHAR(8000), -- List of delimited items
     @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
    ) 
RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) <> 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @sItem = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, 1, CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) - 1))),
            @sInputList = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) + LEN(@sDelimiter), LEN(@sInputList))))

        IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
           INSERT INTO @List 
               SELECT @sItem
        END

        IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
           INSERT INTO @List 
               SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in

        RETURN
END
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: SQL Server has *built in* types that are *designed* to hold multiple values and mechanisms that extract those values (relatively) efficiently. These are *tables* and *xml* (and, more recent versions, *json*). You'll note that "strings containing CSV data" isn't on my list. So why *introduce* obstacles to working well by choosing to use CSV data and then struggling to construct/consume these strings?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```sql
SELECT
    nCmpID, cCompanyName  
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM tbl_CompanyMaster  
     WHERE nCmpID IN (SELECT * 
                      FROM dbo.fnsplit((SELECT can_AccessCompanyID 
                                        FROM tbl_UserMenuRelations 
                                        WHERE nUserID = 0 
                                          AND Is_Active = 1 
                                          AND Is_Available = 1), ',')) 
       AND Is_Active = 1) t
```

there's a useless a) in your code

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

- Will require making use if dynamic Query

  ```
  Declare @Query varchar(8000)

  Declare @CommaSeparatedList varchar(8000)
  ```

  -- Use a string variable to store the result of the split function.

  ```
  Set @CommaSeparatedList =(SELECT * 
                    FROM dbo.fnsplit((SELECT can_AccessCompanyID 
                                      FROM tbl_UserMenuRelations 
                                      WHERE nUserID = 0 
                                        AND Is_Active = 1 
                                        AND Is_Available = 1), ','))

  SET @Query='SELECT
  nCmpID, cCompanyName  
  FROM 
  (SELECT * 
   FROM tbl_CompanyMaster  
   WHERE nCmpID IN ('+@CommaSeparatedList+') a) 
     AND Is_Active = 1) t' 

   Exec(@Query)
  ```

Comment: @marc_s Please check .

Comment: nope no need of dynamic query here.. there's a error in the syntax of his code

Comment: There's no need to put **Answer** at the top. You're writing a response in a box labelled "Your Answer". It's *already* "marked" as an answer by your placing it there (rather than, say, writing it in a comment).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Noted I am new to stackoverflow, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong where you are using user defined function dbo.fnsplit.

You should use cursor for rows by rows execution.

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE record CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM emp
OPEN record

FETCH NEXT FROM record INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
     select * from dbo.fnsplit(@name,',')
    FETCH NEXT FROM record INTO @name
END
CLOSE record
DEALLOCATE record

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel if you do not have to.

Example CSV string splitter  table-valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
create function [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (
      @pstring varchar(8000)
    , @pdelimiter char(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
 return
  with e1(N) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(N) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(N) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , ctetally(N) as (
    select top (isnull(datalength(@pstring),0)) 
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4
  )
  , ctestart(N1) as (
    select 1 union all
    select t.N+1 from ctetally t where substring(@pstring,t.N,1) = @pdelimiter
  )
  , ctelen(N1,L1) as (
    select s.N1,
      isnull(nullif(charindex(@pdelimiter,@pstring,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
    from ctestart s
  )
 select itemnumber = row_number() over(order by l.N1)
      , item       = substring(@pstring, l.N1, l.L1)
   from ctelen l
;
go
```

And use like so:

```
select cm.nCmpID, cm.cCompanyName 
from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
where cm.Is_Active = 1 
  and cm.nCmpId in (
    select s.Item
    from tbl_UserMenuRelations umr
      cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(umr.can_AccessCompanyId,',') s
    where umr.nUserId = 0 
      and umr.Is_Active = 1 
      and umr.Is_Available = 1
    )
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)